# Global Variables in XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am defining some variables in a class file with public static types in my xamarin forms cross platform application. My question is if these variable data somehow accessible by hackers or intruders from apk or ipa files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching a lot on it and finally found XAMARIN.ESSENTIALS "Secure Storage API" which can help us to store our global variable data in a secure and isolated place of mobile phone storage. I hope it might help a lot of people who are not aware of this

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qVivZY0dJE

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your app can be decompiled very easily once someone gets a hold of your IPA or APK files. They will be able to see most of your code. This is a general mobile limitation, and causes huge issues while penetration testing.

And so it is recommended to not place secrets to 3rd party services that you pay for in the app, but to use something like AWS Lambda/Azure Functions or just a backend server to communicate to those services.